# Switching Fusion Tables to SQL Server Google Maps

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

We have been working on some of the database in CSV format and putting them into Google Fusion Tables. But, now is it possible if we can SQL Server to get the data from the database and output a layer with markers to the user.

We want to avoid ASP.NET and C# if possible. We would prefer JS And PHP, but can't seem to find much help regarding the matter.

Does anyone have input on using SQL Server with Google Maps to plot points based on data in the DB?

Comment: There are a number of [articles in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/) about how to use MySQL and PHP; the concepts should apply to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you could do is write a PHP file that queries SQL Server and returns a JSON array. You could then use JS to plot your map points.

Take a look at this blog post: [SQL Server JSON to Table and Table to JSON](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/26/sql-server-json-to-table-and-table-to-json/).

It talks about SQL Server to JSON. They are using it with PowerShell, but one could use it as a starting point for PHP.